# How to EXTEND a blade template only if it exists?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Basically I want to @extend a blade template only if it exists, and if not @extend a different template. There are a few stack overflow answers concerning using @if @endif blocks, but that only works if you are @including a file, not @extending. Ideally something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
@if(some_condition == true)
    @extends('one')
@else
    @extends('two')
@endif
```

If the only way is to use Blade directives, could you please provide an example? Thank you!

Comment: You could check if the file exists using php. `file_exists ($filename )`. I don't know if exists a Laravel way of checking this

Comment: I have done something similar myself but rather than using @extends I had to use `@include('page')` and then within the page file it held @extends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
@extends( $somecondition == true ? 'one' : 'two')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `view:exists`

```
@if(View::exists('path.to.view.one'))
    @extends('one')
@else
    @extends('two')
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `View::exists`

```
@if (View::exists('one'))
    @extends('one')
@else
    @extends('two')
@endif
```

or

`file_exists()` and to get the path use `resource_path()` this,

```
@if (file_exists(resource_path('views/one.blade.php')))
    @extends('one')
@else
    @extends('two')
@endif
```

You can try this, in my case that's working.. See the docs in Laravel - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views

Answer (score 0):

```
@if( file_exists('path to file one'))
    @extends('one')
@else
    @extends('two')
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the conditional to define the **name of the view** you want to load and then simply extend it, for example:

```
@php

 $view = '';

 if (some_condition == true) {
     $view = 'one';
 } else {
      $view = 'two';
 }

@endphp

...

@extends($view)
```

more info

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#php